# How do you set default IRC channels on a server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, irc

I'm helping to setup an ircd-hybrid server at work and I was wondering how to set some default channels on the server.

I've gotten far enough to find how to block some channels with a resv in the ircd.conf file, but I'm not sure how to allow channels.  Any suggestions?

This is a version 7.2.2 ircd-hybrid server on a Hardy Heron Ubuntu server.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you choose this IRCd over another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I used to do is setup up bots to startup channels and the bots get admin right. Then you can find a bot which you can use to control the channel.

Comment: There's no conf file for this?

Comment: afrosteve: IRC bot programs are not part of the IRC server software, They are separate ones like SupyBot(http://sourceforge.net/projects/supybot/)

Comment: I meant conf file for defining the channels, not for controlling the bot.  Sorry, that was unclear.